# Implement circular buffer to write/read arbitrary amount of data in a single call

Tags: c++, data-structures

Most of circular buffer assumes to only read/write ONE object each time, the only link I found to  operates on binary data in form of (const char *bytes, size_t byte_count) is http://www.asawicki.info/news_1468_circular_buffer_of_raw_binary_data_in_c.html, which I feel is not incorrect and a little long. What is the right implementation for that?

I created one myself. but it is still long. Can anybody share a more elegant version? or can you point out is there any thing I can improve in my code to make it short?

```
class Pipe{
    Pipe(size_t capacity): _capacity(capacity){ init();  }
    ~Pipe(){delete [] _buf; }
    size_t read(char* data, size_t bytes);
    size_t write(const char* data, size_t bytes);
   private: 
    //only _capacity-1 is used, one is to identify full or empty.
    void init(){_buf = new char[_capacity]; 
     _wptr = 0; _rptr = 0; _used_size = 0; 
    }
    char* _buf;
    size_t _capacity, _wptr, _rptr, _used_size;
    bool isFull(){return (_wptr + 1 ) % (_capacity) == _rptr;} 
    bool isEmpty(){return _wptr == _rptr;} 
}; 
size_t Pipe::read(char* data, size_t bytes){
    if (isEmpty() || bytes == 0) return 0;
    size_t bytes_read1 = 0, bytes_read2 = 0;
    if (_rptr>=_wptr+1) { //two piece can be read
        bytes_read1 = min(bytes, _capacity - _rptr);
        memcpy(data, _buf + _rptr, bytes_read1);
        _rptr += bytes_read1;
        bytes -= bytes_read1;
        if (_rptr == _capacity) _rptr = 0;
        if (bytes > 0){
        bytes_read2 = min(bytes, _wptr);
            memcpy(_buf + _rptr, data, bytes_read2);
            _rptr += bytes_read2;
            bytes -= bytes_read2;
        }
    }
    else{//one piece can be read
    bytes_read1 = min(bytes, _wptr - _rptr); 
    memcpy(_buf + _wptr, data, bytes_read1);
    _rptr += bytes_read1;
    bytes -= bytes_read1;
    }
    return bytes_read1 + bytes_read2; 
}

size_t Pipe::write(const char* data, size_t bytes){
    if (isFull() || bytes == 0) return 0;
    size_t bytes_write1 = 0, bytes_write2 = 0;
    if (_wptr>=_rptr) { //two piece can be written
        bytes_write1 = min(bytes, _capacity - _wptr); 
        memcpy(_buf + _wptr, data, bytes_write1);
        _wptr += bytes_write1;
        bytes -= bytes_write1;
        if (_wptr == _capacity) _wptr = 0;
        if (bytes > 0){ //_wptr must be 0 here.
            bytes_write2 = min(bytes, _rptr-1);//-1 bcz there is one     
    slot to check empty/full
            memcpy(_buf + _wptr, data+ bytes_write1, bytes_write2);
            _wptr += bytes_write2;
            bytes -= bytes_write2;
        }
    }
    else{ //one piece can be written
        bytes_write1 = min(bytes, _rptr - _wptr -1); 
        memcpy(_buf + _wptr, data, bytes_write1);
        _wptr += bytes_write1;
        bytes -= bytes_write1;
    }
    return bytes_write1 + bytes_write2; 
}
```

Comment: This question is better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: At least the implementer at http://www.asawicki.info/news_1468_circular_buffer_of_raw_binary_data_in_c.html choose better member names (*index* instead of *ptr*). Your class doesn't have any public member function (not even a constructor). I doubt you have tested it. Take a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html , try to write test code which works for boost::circular_buffer<char> and then start to implement it for yourself with these tast cases. Now this is in my opinion an example of bad C++ code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code in OP may be simplified by excluding all conditionals. Original interface and `memcpy` for implementation is retained (only constructor/destructor/read/write made public and unused `_used_size` may be dropped).

```
size_t Pipe::read(char* data, size_t bytes)
{
    bytes = min(bytes, getUsed());
    const size_t bytes_read1 = min(bytes, _capacity - _rptr);
    memcpy(data, _buf + _rptr, bytes_read1);
    memcpy(data + bytes_read1, _buf, bytes - bytes_read1);
    updateIndex(_rptr, bytes);
    return bytes;
}

size_t Pipe::write(const char* data, size_t bytes)
{
    bytes = min(bytes, getFree());
    const size_t bytes_write1 = min(bytes, _capacity - _wptr); 
    memcpy(_buf + _wptr, data, bytes_write1);
    memcpy(_buf, data + bytes_write1, bytes - bytes_write1);
    updateIndex(_wptr, bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```

Several private methods used here may have this simple implementation:

```
size_t Pipe::getUsed()
{ return (_capacity - _rptr + _wptr) % _capacity; }

size_t Pipe::getFree()
{ return (_capacity - 1 - _wptr + _rptr) % _capacity; }

void Pipe::updateIndex(size_t& index, size_t bytes)
{ index = (index + bytes) % _capacity; }
```

This implementation has one disadvantage: it is broken when `_capacity` is close to maximum `size_t` value (because of overflows). This may be fixed by substituting modulo with conditionals in free/used calculations and index updates. Here are modifications for methods used in `read`:

```
size_t Pipe::getUsed()
{
    if (_wptr >= _rptr)
        return _wptr - _rptr;
    else
        return _capacity - _rptr + _wptr;
}

void Pipe::updateIndex(size_t& index, size_t bytes)
{
    if (bytes >= _capacity - index)
        index = index + bytes - _capacity;
    else
        index = index + bytes;
}
```

Comment: @ Evgeny: I do not see difference btw. the first getUser(), UpIndex() and the modified ones. Other than that, the code looks good. Thanks for post the good solution. It does exclude all conditionals and still have the correct logic. It is exactly the answer I am looking for.

Comment: @user389955: first versions use modulo operation, work properly only when `_capacity < MAX_SIZE_T / 2`, and probably are slower than second ones. Second versions use conditionals instead of modulo, their only disadvantage is longer code.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it more short by using boost circular buffer. (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html). All boost libraries are usually very good polished for performance and for implicit specialties on all platforms, so usually I have preference to use them instead of writing my custom codes doing same

Comment: Thanks. I was asked to IMPLEMENT it during an interview that is why I  I want to know how to write my own code.

Comment: Now I see, it was a task, then I guess illustrations on boost documentation page are very helpful for writing own implementations.